# Homogenous Diff Eqn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Definition of Homogenous function:

A function  $f(x)$  is said to be homogeneous of degree $n$ if, by introducing a constant parameter  $\lambda$, replacing the variable  $ x $  with   $\lambda x$   we find:
$f(\lambda x)$ = $\lambda^n f(x)\,.$ 
This definition can be generalized to functions of more-than-one variables; for example, a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ is said to be homogeneous of degree $ n $ if we replace both variables  $x$  and  $y$  by $ \lambda x $ and $ \lambda y$,  we find:
$f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda^n f(x,y)\,.$

My book says that $dy/dt=sin(2t)y$ is homogenous. But isn't

$Q(t,y)dy-P(t,y)dt=0$ where $Q(t,y)=1$ and $P(t,y)=sin(2t)y$

And functions $Q$ and $P$ are not of the same order so the $dt$ and $dy$ coefficients are not of same order thus the Diff eqn is not homogenous ?

Does the same logic apply to

$AB(dy(x)/dx) + y(x)=0$ where A and B are constants ? Also, Both eqns are linear right ?

Comment: @Amzoti Yeah I had it mixed up thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the term *homogeneous* is used to mean that if $y$ is a solution of the differential equation, so is $\lambda\cdot y$ for any constant $\lambda$.

Unfortunately, *homogeneous* has several different meanings and you will have to try to figure out which one is meant in this context...